# array key and value matter

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

I  have an array `$fping` and when its key is equal to a variable(`$probe_name`), how to get the exact value from that array.

```
$fping=array(
    'FPing1'=>$x1,
    'FPing3'=>$x3,
    'FPing5'=>$x5,
    'FPing10'=>$x10,
    'FPing30'=>$x30,
    'FPing60'=>$x60,
    'FPing120'=>$x120,
    'FPing180'=>$x180,
    'FPing300'=>$x300
);

if(array_key_exists($probe_name,$fping)){
    //how to get $x.. value when above if is ok 
}
```

(The variable `$probe_name` gets its value time to time as `$fping` gets its keys. Such as FPing1,FPing3...).

Can I use variable name as a string in `aray_key_exists()`?

Comment: have you tried `$fping[$probe_name]` ?

Comment: thank you  verymuch @ CORRUPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
$fping=array(
    'FPing1'=>$x1,
    'FPing3'=>$x3,
    'FPing5'=>$x5,
    'FPing10'=>$x10,
    'FPing30'=>$x30,
    'FPing60'=>$x60,
    'FPing120'=>$x120,
    'FPing180'=>$x180,
    'FPing300'=>$x300);

if(array_key_exists($probe_name,$fping)){
  $result[] = $fping[$probe_name];
}
```

or

```
$result = array();
$fping=array(
             'FPing1'=>$x1,
             'FPing3'=>$x3,
             'FPing5'=>$x5,
             'FPing10'=>$x10,
             'FPing30'=>$x30,
             'FPing60'=>$x60,
             'FPing120'=>$x120,
             'FPing180'=>$x180,
             'FPing300'=>$x300);

foreach ( $fping as $key => $value ) {
  if ( $key == $probe_name ) {
    $result[] = $value;
  }
}
```